# Subfolder with user settings in user’s local hidden application data folder gets recreated and file itself deleted

Tags: .net, winforms, settings, appsettings

I am building winform applications that are using and saving user settings at run time. Those settings are saved in a file (user.config) in app data folder, all this is done automatically by .net framework. Suddenly my clients started complaining that apps are not working like **settings are gone** or so and it turned out that the folder where the app keeps user.config file got recreated and the file itself was deleted. I've noticed that the folder is still there but another one is created and the app is using that one instead.

Note that this is for **Office VSTO Add-in** for the moment.

**Users were reporting that they didn't reinstall the app** (though that can't be confirmed). That is why I asked this question in the first place.

Here is what it looks like when a new folder is created:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? **Is it possible that Windows (maybe with an update, or even an Office update) reinstalled the app**?

Comment: I would open the folder in the Windows File Explorer and add a breakpoint to wherever the code is for the user.config file, and use the Visual Studio debug features to determine why the folder is being recreated. It sounds like you need to add an if statement to see if the folder has already been created.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code for the user.config file.

Comment: Did this happen after you deployed a new version of the application?

Comment: Where exactly are these folders and what are they named?

Comment: [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade)

Comment: @Jimi users were reporting that they didn't reinstall the app, so Is it possible that Windows (maybe with an update) reinstalled the app?

Comment: They may have moved / copied the application's executable to a different folder

Comment: The Settings mechanism is relatively *dumb*, it's useful for automatic bindings, but you need fail-safes in any case

Comment: No, I don't think so, the app itself is installed in program files and those people only know how to use Office apps. I forgot to note that those apps are VSTO Office add-ins

Comment: ....so it may have something with Office updates too

Comment: Could be. In this context, I suggest replacing application settings with a JSON / XML file stored in `Application.CommonAppDataPath` if you need versioning, or one level up that path for version-agnostic settings, or control versioning using `Application.ProductVersion`, to generate specific folders yourself

Comment: I agree that that would be the best for me, but at the moment I have a dozen apps built on the same principle that needs a quick fix, so I suppose Settings.Default.Upgrade() should do the trick, I also saved other files in those folders too... :(

Comment: @Jimi, ah yes now I see those version numbers in those folders, every time Office hit upgrade it reinstalls the app with a different folder then!